# БЭМ могут ли быть какие-либо глобальные модификаторы или классы

Tags: бэм

что делать если много элементов к примеру одного цвета и хочется сверстать по БЭМ, может ли быть к примеру класс .red который задаст красным элементам цвет, или все же придется писать каждому элементу свой модификатор?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В БЭМ отсутствует понятие глобальных модификаторов, так как имя любого модификатора содержит имя блока или элемента.
Но! Если требуется вынести CSS-свойство за пределы одного блока и применять его к разным БЭМ-сущностям в проекте, необходимо создавать отдельный блок.

Поэтому в БЭМ для того, чтобы единообразно отформатировать целый набор HTML-элементов, используют миксы.

Например:

```
HTML-реализация:

<article class="article text">...</article>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="copyright text">...</div>
</footer>


CSS-реализация:

.text {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
}
```

Из документации:

> https://ru.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81